# Sonar Eclipse not using 'same quality profile as the one used on the server '

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed sonar eclipse on helios on Windowx XPSP3. It is working fine when I analyse the project remotely. But when I select to analyse the project locally, it always runs the analysis in 'Sonar Way' profile. The [documentation](http://www.sonarsource.org/sonar-eclipse-2-0/) for sonar eclipse mentions that "A local analysis uses the same quality profile as the one used on the server for the latest analysis."

Could I have configured it incorrectly? I have followed all steps as mentioned in the document. Is there any setting I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohk, its a mistake on my part.. Misunderstood what the documentation says. The documentation mentions:

> A local analysis uses the same quality profile as the one used on the server for the latest analysis.

But here, on the server means not by selecting 'remotely' in sonar eclipse, but by analyzing the same project with some other runner like the simple java runner. Once the same project, (with same name) is analyzed on the server using the simple java runner, the quality profile used during that run is used when running locally through sonar-eclipse. This also means:

1. The project you wish to analyze using sonar eclipse should have been analyzed on the server already with some other runner, like simple java runner.
2. If quality profile is changed on the server, running the analysis remotely using sonar-eclipse has no effect, analysis must be performed using simple java runner again for it to reflect when running locally.
3. When running locally, sonar-eclipse has to connect to the server anyways.